# Считывания данных из файла и преобразования в список

Tags: python, python-3.x

Для решения задачи мне нужно импортировать данные таким образом:

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open(’aplusb.in’,’r’)
sys.stdout = open(’aplusb.out’,’w’)
a, b = map(int, input().split())
```

Как считать данные таким образом, чтобы образовать список типа int?

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы считать данные из файла и вывести сумму чисел.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, содержимое файла. Вы можете это сделать, нажав кнопку [edit].

Comment: Приведите примеры файлов, задача не понятна

Comment: список типа `int`? может элементов типа `int`?

Comment: и зачем вы в поток загоняете файлы, для открытия есть конструкция `with open()`

Comment: @nomnoms12 Я не могу проверить содержимое файлов, так как сайт для проверки корректности алгоритма сам генерирует содержимое файла

Comment: @andriyIvanchuk Может есть пример содержимого файла? Не гадать же :)

Comment: @nomnoms12 
Даны два числа
первое число количество элементов последовательности
и последовательность чисел, задача состоит в том, чтобы вычислить сумму элементов последовательности пример  (5)  (4 1 8 1 1)   результат должен бить равен 15 
элементы списка типа int

Comment: @andriyIvanchuk Информации недостаточно. Нужно знать, как расположены числа и что выступает в качестве разделителя (перевод строки, пробел и т. п.).

Comment: @andriyIvanchuk Я правильно понял по Вашей правке, что первое число расположено на 1 строке входного файла, а последовательность на второй и разделена пробелами?

Comment: @nomnoms12 Да вы правы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи совсем не обязательно знать первое число. Можно сразу взять вторую строку и разделить её по пробелам методом `split`, а затем преобразовать список строк в список чисел с помощью функции `map`.

Сумму легко вычислить функцией `sum`, она принимает в качестве аргумента список чисел.

Также стоит отметить, что для считывания данных из файла не нужно переопределять стандартные потоки ввода-вывода, используйте контекстный менеджер `with` и `open` (или вовсе без `with`, присваивая результат переменной и вручную закрывая файл).

***Пример:***

```py
with open('aplusb.in') as inp:
    lines = inp.readlines()            # Все строки
    nums = map(int, lines[1].split())  # lines[1] — вторая строка

result = sum(nums)
with open('aplusb.out', 'w') as out:
    out.write(str(result))             # Результат нужно преобразовать в строку
```

***aplusb.in:***

```py
5
4 1 8 1 1
```

***aplusb.out:***

```py
15
```

Answer (score 0):

Если задача состоит в подсчете суммы всех чисел в файле, то вот Вам мое "минималистическое" решение:

***a+b.in***

```
1
2 3 4 5
6 7 8
```

***Код:***

```
num_list = [list(map(int, row.split(' '))) for row in open('a+b.in')]

with open(r'a+b.out', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(sum([n for row in num_list for n in row])))
```

***a+b.out***

```
36
```